# How to handle Multiple modal controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

I have a page that has multiple modals in it. these modals has different functionalities. I want to know how to declare each modals' controllers. should i include them all in the main view? is that a good practice? you check my sample plunker to better understand my question. https://plnkr.co/edit/L0MFwq0nudlkmjJGMerD?p=preview

```
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app-test1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test1Controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="modalOneController.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="modalTwoController.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="row" ng-app="app-test1">
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: >should i include them all in the main view?
.

yes

Comment: But is that the best practice?